# Button not fired up inside asp user control used for umbraco macro

Tags: asp.net, button, macros, event-handling, umbraco

I'm searching solutions for my problem already since 2-3h and I decided better to ask.
I have created and empty web site and the installed umbraco, set up a new macro and it seemd ok but a button is not fired .
The code in Test.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Tests.ascx.cs" Inherits="Demo.Tests" %>
<h1>test</h1>
<form id="Form1" runat="Server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnRunTest" OnClick="onClick_btnRunTest" Text="Run test" runat="server" CausesValidation = "false"/>
</form>

<div style="background-color: #de6363; padding: 10px;">

<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="black" />
    </div>
```

And code behind:

```
public partial class Tests : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //btnRunTest.Click += new EventHandler(this.onClick_btnRunTest);

    }

    public void onClick_btnRunTest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = "";
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        DynSLinkedList<int?> list = new DynSLinkedList<int?>();

        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(18);
        list.Add(-1);
        list.Add(-2);

        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(18);
        list.Add(-1);
        list.Add(-2);

        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(18);
        list.Add(-1);
        list.Add(-2);

        list.Add(1);
        list.Add(18);
        list.Add(-1);
        list.Add(-2);
        list.Remove(18);


        list.Remove(-2);


        list.Remove(1);

        var time = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();
        lblMessage.Text = "Task finished in time "+time +"</br>";
    }


}
```

When I hit the button page reloads but the onClick_btnRunTest is not hit

Comment: Could this be a macro-inside-a-macro issue, perhaps? https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/21908-Razor-macro-not-rendering-when-added-via-Richtext-Editor

Comment: Multiple form tags? I usually see the form tag in the master page near the body tag.

Comment: @pc-pdx The default page is the one that comes on new instalation .The fact is that I have the last version of umbraco 7.2, I also changed the umbracoSettings.config from mvc to web forms but nothing changed